# Flutter Android folder permission

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions

I'm currently using the `permissions` package from pub.dev. I see that it doesn't have a permission that I'm looking for. I'm wondering if there's a permission where I can ask the user for access to the `/Music` folder of the Android device so I can read and write files inside it. Right now I am using the `manageExternalStorage` permission, which I don't like very much.

Comment: What is the use case? Only read from Music?

Comment: Read and write files in the `/Music` folder.

Comment: Then you are stuck with manageExternalStorage. If files are specific only for your app then you don't need external storage.

Comment: There has to be some way of achieve it. I've seen android music apps do something similar without having to use `manageExternalStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `file_picker` had what I needed, I just need to get the user to pick a directory and it tells the user that the app will be able to access the folder.

Comment: do you have any example repo? Currently I was trying to access `Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media` but failed list dir contents.

Comment: @PramUkeshN You can use file picker with an initial directory like so `String? selectedDirectory = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath(initialDirectory: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/");`

Answer (score 0):

you can't ask permission for specific folder, either all storage or nothing,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: That doesn't let me write to files.